# GLSL Matrix Translation Leaves Blank Screen?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix4f that I'm passing from my ShaderProgram class into my vertex shader class using uniform variables. This matrix is supposed to act as a translation for the vertices. The following is what the matrix looks like

```
1, 0, 0, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1
```

When I multiply that variable (Called "test") by the vertex points (Called gl_Vertex) nothing is visible, it just leaves a blank screen. This only happens when I multiply it by the uniform variable "test", if I multiply it by a new matrix4f with the same values, it works normally. If I use vector uniform variables instead of matrices it works as expected.

**Am I passing the variable into the GLSL vertex shader class correctly? And if so, why is my quad not showing up on the screen?**

Here is my vertex shader

```
#version 400 core

uniform vec4 translation;
uniform vec4 size;
uniform vec4 rotation;
uniform mat4 test;

in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 position;
out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

void main(void){
    //pass texture cords
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    //This works by multiplying by identity matrix
    //gl_Position = mat4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) * gl_Vertex;

    //This works by passing vec4's not matrix4
    /*gl_Position = vec4(((gl_Vertex.x + translation.x)*size.x),
                        ((gl_Vertex.y + translation.y)*size.y),
                        ((gl_Vertex.z + translation.z)*size.z),
                        ((gl_Vertex.w + translation.w)*size.w)
                        );*/

    //this leaves a blank window
    gl_Position = test * gl_Vertex;

}
```

This is how I declare the uniform variable locations:

```
translationLocation = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "translation");
sizeLocation = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "size");
rotationLocation = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "rotation");
textureLocation = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "textureSampler");
testMat = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, "test");
```

This is how I render the uniform variables

```
public void start(){
    GL20.glUseProgram(programID);

    Vector4f translation = offset.getTranslation();
    Vector4f size = offset.getSize();
    Vector4f rotation = offset.getRotation();

    GL20.glUniform4f(translationLocation, translation.x, translation.y, translation.z,      translation.w);
    GL20.glUniform4f(sizeLocation, size.x, size.y, size.z, size.w);
    GL20.glUniform4f(rotationLocation, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z, rotation.w);

    FloatBuffer buff = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    offset.getTestTranslation().storeTranspose(buff);
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4(testMat, false, buff);

    GL20.glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
}
```

And this is how I declare my variables before passing it into GLSL

```
Vector4f translation;
Vector4f size;
Vector4f rotation;
Matrix4f testTranslation;

public Offset(){
    translation = new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0);
    size = new Vector4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    rotation = new Vector4f(0, 0 , 0, 0);
    testTranslation = new Matrix4f();
    testTranslation.translate(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Please, don't link to Pastebin. Resources there don't persist, so someday, when the resource will not be available, SO users will not be able to see what you attached. Post the most relevant part of your code directly in the question.

Comment: I apologized but it was removed, I had some trouble pasting it with the correct formatting. Fixed now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I was using the following method to convert the matrix4f into a floatBuffer

```
matrix4f.storeTranspose(buff)
```

When apparently that doesn't properly store the matrix into a float buffer. I'm now using this method to send the matrix to the vertex shader while rendering the shader program

```
public void setMatrixArray(boolean transposed, Matrix4f[] matrices){

    FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16*matrices.length);
    for(int i = 0; i<matrices.length; i++)  {
        matrices[i].store(matrixBuffer);
    }
    matrixBuffer.flip();
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4(testMat,transposed,matrixBuffer);
}
```